# average every 10 minutes worth of data and delete the rest

Tags: mysql

For example I have a table that has the number of people in a room at a given time

```
room_color    people    time
red           100       2012-07-13 11:11:11
red           120       2012-07-13 11:14:12
red           130       2012-07-13 11:17:13
green         ... etc
```

How do I find the average amount of people in the room in a 10 minute interval, for example to summarize the amount of people in the red room at 11:10 to be ~117

I know some ways to do this but it all involves creating a new table, how do I do this without creating a new table? I simply want to delete irrelevant data.

Comment: I am keeping the data source but I need this table to have less data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Insert into room (room_color, people)
( Select color, avg(people) as people from room 
where time between '2012-07-13 11:10' and '2012-07-13 11:20'
Group by room_color )

Delete From room where time between '2012-07-13 11:10' and '2012-07-13 11:20'

-- in case of need set some time to the table
update room set time = '2012-07-13 11:10' Where time is null
```

Try this, if you want you may use two datetime variables and add to one 10 minutes. using the variables in the between clause.

hope this helps.

Comment: thank you but I wanted something that would change the table.

Comment: The updated solution should give you a starting point. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO roomstats
SELECT room_color,AVG(people), '2012-07-13 11:10:00'
FROM roomstats
WHERE room_color = 'red'
    AND DATE(time) = CAST('2012-07-13' AS DATE)
    AND TIME(time) >= CAST('11:10:00' AS TIME)
    AND TIME(time) <= CAST('11:20:00' AS TIME);
```

Could not test this as I am writing it on my phone, on a train. Hope it helps! Will test later.

Comment: thank you but I wanted something that would change the table.